Recommend reference books on homology algebra
I have just started learning homological algebra and hope to get some recommendations for beginner-friendly reference books. Currently, I am reading related content on the Stacks Project and Rotman's "An Introduction to Homological Algebra." Since I have already taken a course in algebraic topology, I would like to be recommended some reference books with a strong background in topology. Additionally, I hope the books have detailed proofs or explanations. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Hilton-Stammbach is readable, has motivation, and details.
